# Regex in between characters

Tags: c#, regex

Im trying to create a regex that will match ascii characters in a string so that they be converted with hex afterwards. The string is received as follows:`<<<441234567895,ASCII,4,54657379>>>` so I am looking to match everything between the third comma and the `>>>` characters at the end of the string like so.

> <<<441234567895,ASCII,4,**54657379**>>>

So far I have managed to create this regex `(/([^,]*,[^,]*)*([^;]*)>>>/)` for it but the third comma is picked up as well which I don't want. What do I need to do to remove it from the match?

thanks Callum

Comment: I'd say that generally speaking, you want to use Regex for patterns that cannot be solved using a few built in `string` functions. `string.Split` is a whole lot easier to understand than a long Regex string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use Regex?

```
string input = "<<<441234567895,ASCII,4,54657379>>>";
string match = input.Substring(3, input.Length - 6).Split(',')[3];
```

You can also use further splits on the beginning and ending padding strings or check their lengths if you want something safer than the Substring magic.

Answer (score 3):

```
(?<=,)[^,]+(?=>>>)
```

This should do it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/79

Comment: Hi there and thanks for your answer, I tried to implement your regex into my project but it was not picking anything up. I wonder if it is because on testing the regex with my string in regex101.com it highlighted the right text but returned no matches in the Match Information cell? I did get the answer below to work though. Thanks again Callum

Comment: @CallumAMacleod (?<=,)([^,]+)(?=>>>) use verbatim mode with @